# Javascript on keypress + sign, how do I retrieve it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript on keypress + sign, how do I retrieve it

Currently I got the following script for my enter key

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function(){

    $("input[type=text]").keyup(function(e){

        if(e.keyCode == "13")
        {
            var nextIndex = $(this).prop('tabindex') + 1;
            var selectedId = $(this).prop('id');
            var rowSplit = selectedId.split("_");
            var rowIn = rowSplit[1];

            if(selectedId.indexOf("big") > -1)
            {

            bigFunction(rowIn)

            $('[tabindex=' + nextIndex + ']').focus();
            }


    $("form :input").on("keypress", function(e) {
    return e.keyCode != 13;
    });


});
</script>
```

I want it to work for if e.g

I got a text field with maxlength 4

I enter 4 random number e.g 1234 and then I press the letter +  sign, I want to change focus to next tabindex

**How do I do it, thanks for helping so much !!**

Comment: I tried and it was 107 if I use the + sign at num lock, what if I shift then press then + sign, how do I capture

Comment: `e.keyCode === 13` is `enter` which will also submit a form by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key code is an integer, you wrote it properly the second time. But the first uses `"13"`.

```
if(e.keyCode == 13)
```

would probably work better. Also the `+` sign code is 43 (0x2B). In JavaScript you could also use the `'+'.charCodeAt(0)` although of course that's much longer.

Also, when you hit enter, the default button is triggered unless you cancel the default behavior as in:

```
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
```

Canceling the default behavior for the `+` would also help to avoid having the `+` appear in the input.

To trigger the auto-tab feature when you have at least 4 characters (be it digits) you want to check the length of the input box value. Probably something like this with jQuery:

```
if($(this).val().length >= 4) ...
```

Otherwise it looks like you already got most of the code as required, although your code sample is currently missing a closing brace (`}`), so I'm not too sure I can help in fixing the code the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

I might do this instead. Example only:

```
$('#element').keypress(function(){
  var v = $(this).val();
  if(v.charCodeAt(v.length-1) === 43){
    // + was pressed
  }
});
```